# About analytic continuation and power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Well, the exercise says:

Suppose $f(z)$ can be continued analytically from a set $E \subset D$ with a limit point $z_o \in D$ into the domain $D$ itself.

Let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(z-z_0)^k$ for $|z-z_0|<\Delta_0$. Where $\Delta_0$ is the distance from $z_0$ to the boundary of $D$, let $\{z_k\}$ be a sequence of point of $E$ converging to $z_0$.

How can the coefficients $a_0,a_1,...,a_n,...$ be deduced from a knowledge of $f(z)$ on a set $E$?

Idea: well, I tried to apply Taylor series expansion. However, I didn't get enough 
. So, I began with inductive steps as follows:

\begin{align}
a_0 &= \lim_{k \to \infty }f(z_k) \\
a_1 &= \lim_{k \to \infty } \dfrac{f(z_k)-a_0}{z_k-z_0} \\
a_n &= \lim_{k \to \infty }\dfrac{f(z_k)-a_0-a_1(z_k-z_0)-\cdots -a_{n-1}(z_k-z_0)^{n-1}}{(z_k-z_0)^k}
\end{align}

Now, I'm stuck here. I'll really appreciate any other idea.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do you need another idea?  You wrote down the answer.  What did you not get enough of?

Comment: Well, I thought there would be another way to find such coefficients less explicitly or applying the hypothesis $z_0$  is a limit point and then it could be simplified a bit more. Thanks for answer, Sir.